# is suki an adjective and a verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs, adjectives, na-adjectives, parts-of-speech

I thought that "suki" was a verb which meant "to like". It is hard to me to make sense why it seems to be always used with "desu".

Now in a webpage I read that suki is an adjective, which means something like "liked" like some sort of passive voice I guess? That's why it uses the verb desu almost always I supposed. But I also see in another webpage that suki is a verb with all its conjugations.

The question is, is it suki an adjective, a verb, or both, and if it's also a verb, when it's used like a verb with its respective conjugations and without desu? (Assuming it can be used without desu.)

Comment: Generally speaking, the more romaji a website uses, the more misinformation it gives.

Comment: Even though 好き is an adjective, it doesn't mean it corresponds with English adjectives like "likable" etc. Grammatical error over 好き often stems from believing 好き is "likable".

Comment: @torazaburo you know, after this topic and before your comment I was exactly thinking about that, if the notion of nouns, verbs and adjectives are the same in english and japanese. At least I found that in my native language (spanish) we also use verbs as nouns and as some sort of adjectives, something I didnt realize before. May be they should be called by their original japanese names Keiyōshi, Meishi
which might have different connotations

Comment: @torazaburo The things you're typing should really be posted as an answer rather than as comments.

Comment: in english can't you just use any adjective that way? and they dont have any special noun characteristic because of that? it's beautiful, strong, tall, etc. it's a dog, cat, house, etc. when in other japanese adjectives you can't say (adjective) da ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

好き *suki* is a difficult word.

What is clear is that it derives from the verb 好く *suku*, which is still in use (most often in the passive voice: 好かれる "to be liked").

However, like the 連用形 *ren'yōkei* "*masu*-stem" of so many other verbs, it took on a life of its own, primarily as what is quite naturally analyzed as 形容動詞 *keiyōdōshi* "*na*-adjective".

Hence we have

> 1. 〇〇が好きです
>    〇〇 *ga suki desu*
>    <sub>cf. 〇〇がきれいです</sub>
> 2. 好き**な**〇〇
>    *suki **na*** 〇〇
>    <sub>cf. きれい**な**〇〇</sub>

A literal translation might be "X is *likeable/nice*", which equates to "I like X".

---

Note that 嫌い *kirai* (from 嫌う *kirau*, also often seen in the passive 嫌われる) works almost exactly the same.

Comment: 「ペキフルーツが好きじゃない」
「ペキフルーツが嫌いです」

「嫌いなペキフルーツ」

Answer (score 0):

好き is indeed tricky and I was also tricked when I was learning to use this word. 好き is a *na*-adjective 形容動詞. To be abstract, it means the "quality of being liked", which is different from "likable" (好かれる or 好ましい). If this confuses you, there are two rules of thumb:

- 好きだ/好きです is the closest equivalent to the English verb "like". e.g. モーニング娘。のことが**好き**です means "(I) like Morning Musume", NOT "Morning Musume is likable".
- **好き**な〇〇 means "the liked 〇〇". e.g. 好きな人 means "the person (someone) likes".

Once you understand these two rules, use 好き as you would any *na*-adjective. e.g., "liked" is 好きだった/好きでした, and "don't like" is 好きじゃない.

(and I do like Morning Musume)